# jquery doesn't find a selected node after populating selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var opt = new Option('test','test', true, true);

$('#country option:selected').selectedIndex
```

So i've populated the selectbox, and jQuery can't find the selected option using the script below, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `selectedIndex` on `option` instead of `select`. You need `dom` select object to call `selectedIndex` not the jQuery obejct. Use the id selector to get the select jQuery object and then use indexer to get the DOM select object to call `selectedIndex` on it.

```
$('#country')[0].selectedIndex
```

or using javascript

```
document.getElementById('country').selectedIndex
```

To get the selected option `option:selected` and to get the index of selected option you can call index()

```
$('#country option:selected').index()
```

Comment: how do I find the selected option?

Comment: $('#country option:selected')

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#country').find('option:selected')....
```